# Why is $2\sum_{k=0}^{n}4^k = \frac{2}{3}(2^{2k+2}-1)$?

Tags: summation

I read it in a text saying they got there using standard techniques but I'm really rusty with this stuff because I've tried to prove it and don't seem to go anywhere.

Comment: You could try to prove it using induction

Comment: Hint: Try to prove it by induction.

Comment: I know I can prove it with induction, but how would I go if I needed to reach the right side just from the left side?

Comment: Then please show us you know how to prove with induction.  Without showing us what you tried, you wrote an empty claim.

Comment: Multiply the two polynomials $(x-1) \times (1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n) ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ to get some polynomial $f(x)$.  Then conclude from this that $\displaystyle \frac{f(x)}{x - 1} = (1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^n) ~: ~x \neq 1.$  Then, apply this conclusion to your posted question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first several terms being added are 1, 4, 16,64,256, and so on. So the first terms of the sum are:

$a_0=1$, $a_1=5$, $a_2=21 $,$a_3=85$, ...

Notice each term is 1 more than 4 times the previous term. Four times the first N terms produces N more terms of the sequence, N-1 that are already there, then essentially swapping the 1 with the next term in the sum. So add 1 to complete the series. This can be proven more rigorously with induction.

Frequently a formula for a sum can be deduced if you have two rules for generating subsequent terms.

We have both:

$a_{n+1}=a_n+4^{n+1}$, by definition of the series.

$a_{n+1}=4a_n +1$, by the above observation.

So $a_n+4^{n+1}=4a_n+1$.

Solve for $a_n$.

$a_n=\frac{4^{n+1}-1}{4-1}=\frac{2^{2n+2}-1}{3}$